# How to show date in normal format in jqgrid when formatter is used

Tags: jqgrid

Date column is created using colmodel below.
This column shows values like  0101.0101.7070  for every date column.
if formatter:date is removed, date is correct.

How to show normal date values with  formatter:date ?

```
{ "name":"Date",
"formatter":"date",
"datefmt":"dd.mm.yyyy",
"formatoptions":{"newformat":"dd.mm.yyyy"},
"editable":true
}
```

**Update.**

Data is passed from server using json in same dd.mm.yyyy format like

```
{"total":2,"page":1,"records":57,"rows":
[{"id":"9279","cell":["9279","42","","10.08.2011","","","","False"]},
 {"id":"9278","cell":["9278","41","","12.08.2011","","","","False"]},
```

...

Using d.m.y formats in column options as suggested shows proper dates but with 2 year digits only.. 
I'm looking for a 4-digit year numbers. I tried d.m.yyyy format but this shows 8 digit year numbers and 1 for month and day as  01.01.70707070

I also tried to add srcformat: 'dd.mm.yyyy' to formatoptions but this does not change the wrong result.

Comment: Which format has input data for the column? Could you include the corresponding examples?

Comment: @Oleg: thank you. all data is is dd.mm.yyyy format. I updated question and added source data sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display the day as the number you should use `j` or `d`. For the displaying month as the number you should use `n` or `m`. The `d` and `m` includes `0` padding at the beginning if needed. The 'y' means two digit year format and `Y` means four digit year.

So you probably need `srcformat: 'd.m.Y'` or `srcformat: 'j.n.Y'`.

Comment: thank you. This seems to work. Some users may have different date format. How to show date in user browser culture format ?

Comment: @: Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Localization1.htm) from [the feature request](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/small-changes-in-i18ngrid-locale-xx-js-files-to-make-possible-dynamic-language-switching/#p22314) about the subject. The demo display the grid in the web browser language (`navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage`) and allows the user additionally to change the language dynamically. For the implementation one needs only some modifications in the `grid.locale-XX.js` files and **not in the main jqGrid code**.

Comment: thank you. This sample has hard coded colmodels containing hard coded date formats for every culture there is no fallback so in my culture et grid does not appear at all initially. How to use same colmodel but present dates in browser culture ? asp .net controller ui culture is set according to browser culture. If is reasonalbe to force mvc controller to send dates to jqGrid in browser culture format and send also date formats to browser. How to return date format required by jqgrid from .net mvc controller ?

Comment: @Andrus: [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Localization1.htm) had small bug. Thanks. It's fixed. It should use `en-US` date format and English texts for "unknown" browser locales like your. The demo demonstrate 1) how to detect the web browser language (`navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage`) **before** the grid will be created and how to use the corresponding `colModel` template which contain the `date` definition. If only the `date` format is interesting for you, you can simplify the code or write your own one.

Comment: thank you. Controller can pass dates in localized format to jqGrid. In this case only single proper local date format string needs also passed to jgGrid colmodel. How to return proper date format string from ASP .NET MVC controller to jqGrid? For expample in .NET date format dd.mm.yyyy should be passed to jqGrid as d.m.Y  . Is there some function in .NET which returns jqGrid (PHP?) date format string for current thread UI culture?

Comment: @Oleg with your [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Localization1.htm) I could see you have explicitly defined the date format for colModelEN_GB,colModelEN_IN. Can I have in column model always `formatoptions:{newformat:'Shortdate'}` and based on the region display the correct format?

Comment: @Oleg If I give the `formatoptions:{newformat:'ShortDate'}`  for **colModelEN_GB,colModelEN_IN** then it will not display in 'd/m/Y' for colModelEN_GB and 'd-m-Y' for colModelEN_IN. Is there any thing by which we can specify it to display in correct format?

Comment: @SanjuRao: How you defined `colModelEN_GB` and `colModelEN_IN`? Do you defined `grid.locale-XX.js` for EN_GB and EN_IN? Which version and fork of jqGrid yo use? `ShortDate` format is just shortcut for `"n/j/Y"` (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js#L190)). Do you detect locale or you specify locale explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

Use d.m.y instead of dd.mm.yy  ,

Comment: thank you. Yuor suggestion shows 2-digit years. How to show 4-digit year numbers ?